# My .mp4 file in the 'raw' folder cannot be played. On emulator it says 'Can't play this video'. How to solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build a video player app in android. I uploaded an mp4 file in the 'raw' folder of my project. I am getting the error 'Can't play this video.' I am using the following code to create a videoView and MediaController instances. The mp4 file is just a 40 second video.

```
package com.example.video_player

import android.R
import android.net.Uri
import android.net.Uri.*
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import android.os.Bundle

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.example.video_player.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(binding.testview.id)

        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)

        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(
            "android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + "BrahMos"
        )

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()

    }


}
```

Comment: try to get the uri using this code `val uri = Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(packageName)
    .appendPath("${R.raw.your_video_name}")
    .build()`